# Android sqlite IN statement query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi i am new to sqlite and i am having trouble with the IN (?) statement

my query is

```
where = SQLDB.KEY_POINT_BOX_ID_COLUMN + " IN (?) ";
whereArgs2 = {myStrings} // myStrings = [1,2]
Cursor cursor2 = db.query(SQLDB.DATABASE_TABLE_POINT,
            result_columns, where, whereArgs2, null, null,
            null);
```

This query doesn't return anything but if i change the above where statement to

```
where = SQLDB.KEY_POINT_BOX_ID_COLUMN + " = 1 ";
```

I get results

How do i use the IN(?) correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7418849

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1309989

Comment: i tried myString = ["1,2"] and ["'1,2'"] which didn't help. One of those post is python i don't understand how they help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using whereArgs and just used this statement

```
where = SQLDB.KEY_POINT_BOX_ID_COLUMN + " IN ("+idValues+") "; // idValues = '1','2'
```