# sqlite3 "IN" clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table with different columns (pageNum, value1, value2, value3).

I want to do something like that in python3.3 and sqlite3:

```
selection = (100, 200, 300)

cursor.execute(""" SELECT value1, value3
                  FROM myTable
                  WHERE value2>? and pageNum IN ?
                  """, (10, selection))
```

But seems like it is complaining:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Note that the question is about how to use the `IN` clause that way, not about how to do the query, which of course in that case it could be done in a different way.

Comment: You eiter have to use more than one `?` in your `IN` clause or convert yout tuple into string first.

Comment: @konart you should never, ever convert your tuple into a string.... also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause not super nice, but does get around the problem

Comment: @user3012759 care to tell why?

Comment: yes I am also curious to know, and the answer in the other post does not seem to clear at least for me.

Comment: @konart added answer explaining what and where a bit better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter substitution for a SQLite "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer from Alex Martelli is essentially solving your problem since python support for the `IN` is quite unwieldy, and in essence you have to provide as many `?` as you have values in your collection.

```
selection = (100, 200, 300)
questionmarks = '?' * len(selection)
formatted_query = 'SELECT value1, value3 FROM myTable
              WHERE value2>? AND pageNum IN ({})'.format(','.join(questionmarks))
query_args = [10]
query_args.extend(selection)
result_set = c.execute(formatted_query, query_args)
```

the above code should do, and heres bit of explanation on what it does:

It essentially prepares the sql statement with as many `?` as you need and then executes the query with all your arguments supplied in a list so sqlite will take care of escaping the values.

If you convert your query to a string you will have to make sure that you sanitize the values yourself which is not recommended.