# how to use python list in %sql query

Tags: python, mysql, ipython, jupyter

I am using the [sql](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) package in a Jupyter notebook and I understand how to use variables in my query:

```
client = "Disney"
queryid = %sql SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :client
```

What I don't understand is how to pass a list to my query, like:

```
clients = ["Disney", "Netflix", "Sky"]
queryid = %sql SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name in (:clients)
```

This raises an error which states that my SQL is wrong. What is the way to handle lists in this setting?

Comment: If you're passing a list, are you sure `=` operator is still valid? You may want `IN` or the like.

Comment: What do you want?  Items that match any thing in the list?

Comment: Other SO questions about `where in` concatenate the list strings into one string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter

Comment: @hpaulj the point is to have the right sintax for this particular way to use MySQL

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes of course I'll update my question

Comment: `... name in (?), ', '.join(alist)` maybe

Comment: @hpaulj either you know or you don't, there is no try... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a demo case for `sqlite3`:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3
In [2]: conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
In [3]: c = conn.cursor()
In [4]: c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
   ...:              (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
   ...: 
   ...: # Insert a row of data
   ...: c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.1
   ...: 4)")
   ...: 
   ...: # Save (commit) the changes
   ...: conn.commit()
   ...: 
In [5]: # Larger example that inserts many records at a time
   ...: purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
   ...:              ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
   ...:              ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
   ...:             ]
   ...: c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

I can fetch values that match several strings with:

```
In [31]: c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (?,?)',('IBM','RHAT'))
Out[31]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xaf703fa0>
In [32]: c.fetchall()
Out[32]: 
[('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14),
 ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

Or with the generalized solution from [Parameter substitution for a SQLite "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause)

```
In [33]: alist=['RHAT','IBM']
In [34]: c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (%s)' %
    ...:                            ','.join('?'*len(alist)), 
    ...:                            alist)
    ...:                            
Out[34]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xaf703fa0>
In [35]: c.fetchall()
Out[35]: 
[('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14),
 ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

`c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (:1,:2)',alist)`, and possibly other forms.

see also:

[sqlite3 "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473451/sqlite3-in-clause)

I assume `MYSQL` and `%sql` iterface behaves the same; but I don't have those installed.

---

With proper quoting literals also work (again `sqlite3`)

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN ("IBM","RHAT")')
```

or

```
In [80]: 'SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (%s)'%','.join('"%s"'%x for x in alist)
Out[80]: 'SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN ("RHAT","IBM")'
In [81]: c.execute(_)
```

So I'm guessing that:

```
%sql SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN ("IBM","RHAT")
```

would work even if some form of `(:....)` does not.

---

I installed `%sql`

```
In [5]: %%sql
   ...: sqlite:///example.db
   ...: 

Out[5]: 'Connected: None@example.db'
In [7]: %sql SELECT * from stocks
Done.
Out[7]: 
[('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14),
 ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000.0, 72.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]

In [9]: %sql SELECT * from stocks where symbol in ('IBM')
Done.
Out[9]: 
[('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]

In [10]: %sql SELECT * from stocks where symbol in ('IBM','RHAT')
Done.
Out[10]: 
[('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14),
 ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

The string formatting approach works:

```
In [11]: alist=['RHAT','IBM']
In [12]: cmd='SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN (%s)'%','.join('"%s"'%x for x
    ...:  in alist)
In [13]: cmd
Out[13]: 'SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol IN ("RHAT","IBM")'
In [14]: %sql $cmd
Done.
Out[14]: 
[('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14),
 ('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

The `:` syntax isn't well documented.  It isn't clear who's implementing it. (`$` is standard Ipython variable substitution).

```
In [18]: sym='IBM'
In [19]: %sql SELECT * from stocks where symbol in (:sym)
Done.
Out[19]: 
[('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

`symbol in (:sym1,:sym2)` works

So far I don't see evidence that `%sql` works with the conventional SQL placeholder syntax.

---

Looks like you (?) submitted and closed a issue on github, https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/92

Adapting that solution to quote strings:

```
In [74]: mystring = '({})'.format(','.join('"{}"'.format(e) for e in alist))
In [75]: mystring
Out[75]: '("RHAT","IBM")'
In [76]: %sql SELECT * from stocks where symbol in $mystring
Done.
```

In other words, use the `ipython` `$` injection as opposed to the `:` form.

---

Looking at the `ipython-sql` source code:

```
ipython-sql/blob/master/src/sql/run.py
def run(conn, sql, config, user_namespace):
    ...
    txt = sqlalchemy.sql.text(statement)
    result = conn.session.execute(txt, user_namespace)
```

It looks like the `:name` syntax is a `sqlalchemy` bind parameter, and is handled with `sqlalchemy.sql.text` and `sqlalchemy.sql.bindparam`

(http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#orm-tutorial-literal-sql)

This error indicates that each bindparameter is translated into a `?` placeholder, plus as matching `parameters` entry:

```
In [96]: %sql SELECT * from stocks where symbol in :mystring
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "?": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT * from stocks where symbol in ?'] [parameters: ('("RHAT","IBM")',)]
```

So my original solution of generating `IN (?,?,...)` to match the length of the list is the right SQL, even though it does not work with `sqlalchemy` and `%sql`.

Comment: thanks for your time, but as I said before, either you have a solution for %sql or you don't...

Comment: I've downloaded `%sql` and got a solution working with the `Ipython` `$` syntax.  Conventional SQL placeholder syntax apparently does not work with `%sql` and `sqlalchemy` which has its own `bindparameters` syntax.

Comment: This is a fantastically thorough answer that really anticipates future visits to this question. The %sql version worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

Removing parentheses works for me.

```
clients = ["Disney", "Netflix", "Sky"]
queryid = %sql SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name in :clients
```

Answer (score 0):

This function saves me from this kind of problem:

```py
> def splitParam(param): # this function splits multiple values of filter
    filteredParam = ""
    if param:
        for item in param:
            if filteredParam=="":
                filteredParam += "'" + item.upper() + "'"
            else:
                filteredParam += ", '" + item.upper() + "'"

    return filteredParam
```

Answer (score -1):

Anecdotal note about applying the $ with python tuples in a SQL query:

It needs to be used in a %sql line, it cannot* be used in a %%sql code block.
Use line continuation backslashes for readability on the query.

*as far as I can tell