# escape a single quote from a downloaded value sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am saving locations on a web page to an sqlite3 database using python/selenium and sqlite3. Some of the locations contain a single quote

For example maryville, John's lane, London

I know that when creating a data base locally, I must use two single quotes to escape this. John''s lane. REF:- questions/603572/how-to-properly-escape-a-single-quote-for-a-sqlite-database
How can this be achieved when scraping a website.

My Code is below:-

```
# get locations
locs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("meta")
for loc in locs:
    if loc.text !="":
        print loc.text
        query += ",\'"+loc.text.replace(', ','-')+"\'"
```

I get this error because of the presence of the 's

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES("+query+");")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

I am saving the full address to one fields. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't escape and catenate values to SQL, use placeholders: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1310001/2681632. There are enough SQL injections around already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use placeholders instead of manually trying to escape your data.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('create table locations (name text)')
locs = list(map("{}'s".format, range(100)))
conn.execute('insert into locations values ({})'.format(
    '), ('.join(['?'] * len(locs))  # Build your placeholders
), locs)
print(list(conn.execute('select * from locations limit 5')))
```

will print

```
[("0's",), ("1's",), ("2's",), ("3's",), ("4's",)]
```

A question mark in the query to execute signifies a placeholder and your DB-API ([sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html) in this case) will handle replacing those with the data you provide. It'll also handle required escaping.

Also you should consider using [`executemany`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany), since manually building a huge placeholder list for `VALUES (?), (?), (?), ...` will cause

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: too many terms in compound SELECT
```

so do

```
conn.executemany('insert into locations values (?)', ((x,) for x in locs))
```

and you can insert thousands of rows.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.