# How to convert the datatype from Integer to Text?

Tags: python, sqlite

For one Column situation, the the duplicated question with answer is shown in: [Parameter substitution for a SQLite "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause)

I want to copy data from `ColA` and `ColB` of the `oldTable` into the `newTable`. The `ColA` and `ColB` in `oldTable` have datatype of `INTEGER`.

By copying the data, I also want to check if `ColA or ColB` are a part of a string (in this case, the `TextTemp`).

My problem is: `ColA` and `ColB` have the datatype of `INTEGER`, and the `TextTemp` is `TEXT` format. Different datatype cannot be compared.

Thus the question: How can I convert data in `ColA` and `ColB` from `INTEGER` into `TEXT`?

Here is my code in Python. The 15, 3, 44 and 9 from `ColA or ColB` should be copied.

```
TextTemp = "15 3 44 9"  #String format, but all numbers, with empty spaces
TextTemp = "15 3 44 9".split() #Convert TextTemp into TEXT format
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE newTable AS  
             SELECT * FROM oldTable 
             WHERE ColA IN (%s)
             OR ColB IN (%s)''' % 
             (','.join('?'*len(TextTemp)), TextTemp)
             (','.join('?'*len(TextTemp)), TextTemp))
```

The error message: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

I am pretty sure that the code above is very near its final correct version, but I just don't know how to change it.

PS: I cannot use a for loop, so please help me to solve the problem in the above method.

Comment: Do `TextTemp = "15 3 44 9".split()` and follow the instructions in the dupe target. In addition to forming the parameterized query string just pass the split `TextTemp` as the 2nd argument to `cur.execute` as is (it'll be the argument sequence). SQLite is pretty [lenient](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparison_example) when it comes to types, so you should be able to compare them.

Comment: the duplicate applies, except you need to use `?` for the actual final placeholder

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for your comment and help. I tried but didnot found the duplicated question. Hier I updated my question, could you please have a look on it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the comment. I updated the question, could you please have a look on this one? Thanks.

Comment: @IljaEverilä  Yes, I am a beginner. Could you tell me how to write the code? Your link is too long for such a short problem. :-) Could you also remove your duplicate mark to this question? Thanks.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Could you remove your duplicate mark to this question? Because I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easiest to make placeholders for the query outside the `cur.execute`.
Both of your `in` queries need *n* comma separated question marks.

```
>>> to_find = "15 3 44 9"  # String format, but all numbers, with empty spaces
>>> to_find = to_find.split() # Convert TextTemp into TEXT format
>>> to_find
['15', '3', '44', '9']
>>> placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(to_find))
>>> placeholders
'?,?,?,?'
```

Then we fill in the query. I will use `.format` instead of the old-style formatting as it is easier to substitute the same value many times with the new-style formatting:

```
>>> query = '''CREATE TABLE newTable AS  
               SELECT * FROM oldTable 
               WHERE ColA IN ({0})
               OR ColB IN ({0})'''.format(placeholders)
>>> print(query)
CREATE TABLE newTable AS  
               SELECT * FROM oldTable 
               WHERE ColA IN (?,?,?,?)
               OR ColB IN (?,?,?,?)
```

As each `?` is bound to a distinct parameter from the parameter list and we now have 2 * n placeholders, we need to duplicate the substituted values too, hence `tofind * 2`:

```
>>> to_find * 2
['15', '3', '44', '9', '15', '3', '44', '9']
>>> cur.execute(query, to_find * 2)
```

And here's the code in final compact form

```
to_find = to_find.split()
placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(to_find))
query = '''CREATE TABLE newTable AS  
           SELECT * FROM oldTable 
           WHERE ColA IN ({0})
           OR ColB IN ({0})'''.format(placeholders)
cur.execute(query, to_find * 2)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your superb answer! It works! I would not even think of these codes. Splendid! Thanks!