# Correct way to "select * from tbl where field in ?" and the placeholder is a list without string interpolation

Tags: python, pysqlite

I have a query of this form using pysqlite:

```
query = "select * from tbl where field1 in ?"
variables = ['Aa', 'Bb']
```

In a query, I'd like this to work:

```
with conn.cursor() as db:
  res = db.execute(query, (variables,)).fetchall()
```

eg, interpreted into SQLITE command line as:

```
select * from tbl where field1 in ("Aa", "Bb");
```

But this fails with:

```
pysqlite3.dbapi2.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I understand I can just string.join([mylist]), but this is unsafe. How can I use placeholder parameters and a list in sqlite with python?

### Update

Differentiating this [from similar questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause), they seem to be looking to use %s string interpolation where I am looking to avoid this

Comment: `fields = ("Aa", "Bb")`                                                                                                        
===================           `result_set = c.execute('select * from tbl where field1 IN (%s)' % ("?," * len(fields))[:-1], fields)`

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking for how to do this safely using placeholder ? syntax rather than with string interpolation.

Comment: This already takes care of sql injection is when you use `?`, But still I'm too looking for that. reading the same too.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Parameter substitution for a SQLite “IN” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309989/parameter-substitution-for-a-sqlite-in-clause)

Comment: @BryanOakley, I believe that user was looking for something different, because the accepted answer there uses string interpolation.

Comment: I'm assuming the length of `variables` is not known and may vary?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: `WHERE field IN ?` and the placeholder is a list without string interpolation

- Values are a list of `int`

  ```
  values = (42, 43, 44)
  ```
- Prepare your Query with the number of bindings

  ```
  bindings = '?,'*len(values)
  QUERY = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN ({});".format(bindings[:-1])

  print("{}".format(QUERY))
  ```

  > **Output**:
  >
  > ```
  > SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN (?,?,?);
  > ```
- Execute the Query

  ```
  cur.execute (QUERY, values)
  ```