# sqflite IN operator with AND operator

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have following query which select from employee table where name is "max" and ID not in 123 and 444.
Not in IDs can grow in future. But I am receiving error as

**Error**

( 8023): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "?": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:

**Query**

```
     List<String> a = [];
        a.add("123");
        a.add("444");

        var table = await mydb.rawQuery(
            "SELECT value from employee  WHERE employeename = ? AND id NOT IN ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC",
            ["max", a]);
```

Comment: This is in flutter, Which uses Dart Language.

Comment: Yes i got that. Is the `LIST` value fixed? I mean is it 2 always? If so,one way is that the parameter (`?`) should match no of values. something like `..NOT IN (?,?) ...` and put the values in `whereArgs: a` or you have to join the values with `,`..something like `id IN (${a.join(', ')})`

Comment: List of values will be changing, Now 2 but in future can be 5 , 6. depend on scenario

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `LIST` is unpredictable, one way is that you can use `JOIN` to create your select statement with required value of `NOT IN`. Below is one sample.

```
void main() {
  List<String> a = [];
  a.add("123");
  a.add("444");

  var select =
      'SELECT value from employee  WHERE employeename = ? AND id NOT IN (\'' +
          (a.join('\',\'')).toString() +
          '\') ORDER BY timestamp DESC';

  var table = await mydb.rawQuery(select, ["max"]);
}
```

If you print the variable select you will get

```
SELECT value from employee  WHERE employeename = ? AND id NOT IN ('123','444') 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC.
```

Then you can pass the above statement to `rawquery` and get your result.

P.S:Use your single quote and double quote accordingly.

Comment: Solution worked. this is pro level. I could optimize the code due to this.

Comment: You're just asking for a Bobby Tables SQL Injection attack if any of your SQL is done by producing a string at runtime.  Please don't do that.  That's what placeholders are for! https://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @Randal Schwartz, I agree, This code is prone to SQL injection. I was trying to solve OP's existing problem. I will add a word of caution to the answer and will try to provide an alternate Query avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: This is just asking for SQL injection. Dont do this!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ah! After hours I find your solution !

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for @arun-palanisamy 's solution, see [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215540/sqflite-in-operator-with-and-operator#comment104698023_59215540). Props go to him. I just tried the following -- with Groovy/Postgres, but the error seems to be the same, so you might want to give it a try:

```
String[] a = ['123', '444']

// your code, throws 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"':
// def table = sql.execute("SELECT value from employee WHERE employeename = ? AND id NOT IN ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC", ["max", a])

// code of arun-palanisamy, compiles:
def table = sql.execute("SELECT value from employee WHERE employeename = ? AND id NOT IN (${a.join(', ')}) ORDER BY timestamp DESC", ["max", a])
```

Side notes:

- You might want to try a different type for `a`, such as Array in my code, or even a HashMap.
- There are examples (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309989/3890673)) where the number of `?` are generated dynamically.

Update: Go for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244836/3890673), we posted simultaneously

Comment: This is a possible SQL Injection attack. DO NOT DO THIS. Use placeholders. Do not generate SQL at runtime from program data.  https://bobby-tables.com